# An ideal statistical method to compare two sets of data: a 't-test', '2 sample Kolmogorov Smirnov', or 'cucconi test'

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics

I have a set of data points that represent the cardiac function of an animal's heart every quarter of a second, over a certain period. The data points were subjected to [ZhangFit](https://pypi.org/project/BaselineRemoval/) for baseline correction. Here, you can find [the overlapping baseline-corrected and uncorrected graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvh9t.png) I would like to check whether these two datasets(raw data and baseline-corrected) differ from a statistical point of view. When read about it, I was a bit confused as to what statistical method could be used: Whether a 't'-test, 'Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test' or a
Cucconi test. I happened to hear about the Cucconi test while reading about the KS-test, but I don't have much knowledge about it. Can someone help me identify which of these statistical methods would be ideal in this case?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what hypothesis you are trying to test.  Most of the tests you mention assume some sort of independence assumptions, which don't seem relevant to your two highly correlated time series.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, this is not the right approach. The statistical tests you named are hypothesis tests, meaning, you have samples that come from certain distributions, and you want to prove something about these unknown distributions.

That is not your case. You have data collected over time from an individual, and you want to check how much these two different measures differ. Maybe someone more familiar with this type of analyses can better help you. But I don't think hypothesis testing is the right way.

To specifically find what you want, you should be more specific about what you need to analyse exactly. Your question could be answered with a correlation measure. Or alternatively, if you subtracted one dataset from the other and normalized this, you would obtain a measure of how much they different at each point in time.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, paired t-test could be an option since you have repeated measurements. However, I would rather check non-parametric alternatives, such as Wilcoxon signed-rank test. The reason lies in the [assumptions](https://www.statology.org/paired-t-test-assumptions/) the parametric t-test has.